# Using NodeJS, How to upload a file into azure container / directory (such as: test-container/folder-test)

Tags: node.js, directory, containers, azure-storage

I am able to upload file to azure on specific container but I am not able to find any directory reference from azure documentation for Nodejs.

While using c# and Java we are able to upload on specific directory of container (sub directories)

Nodejs:

```
    var BlobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccount, accessKey);
    BlobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(container, BlobName, FilePath,
            function(error, result, response) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else {
                    console.log("uploaded to azure");
                }
            }
```

The above written piece of code works fine as I receive file to specific container..

but I need to upload to directory of container, anyone have encountered this issue before please help. I have found ways in Java but I need to use Nodejs

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution already

Comment: Just added directory with blobName e.g: folder-test/cube.obj and it successfully uploads to specific directory :)

Comment: Great solution, you can post it as an answer for us to refer. It seems storage sdk developers originally want us to use this method instead of the `in container name` one, as the folder is virtual.

Comment: @SkSunny thanks Great Solution can please post the solution as answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i have tried and find the solution just by adding the directory name append to blobName. when calling the function just call it like below

```
     let subDirecory = "Upload";
     let BlobName = subDirecory + "/" + "BlobName"
```